# Как на контроллере PERC H730 настроить два независимых RAID? Ctrl+R при загрузке недоступно

Tags: raid, dell

Всем доброго времени суток!
Прошу прощения за глупый вопрос, только разбираюсь в теме. Итак. Есть сервер Dell PowerEdge T630 c RAID-контроллером PERC H730. К нему подключены 5 SATA SSD. Планируется из двух сделать RAID 1 под систему и из остальных трех RAID 5 под данные. Насколько я понимаю H730 может работать в двумя независимыми RAID.
Как создать один RAID - понятно. Но как сделать второй? В мануалах, какие нашел, такую операцию делают через конфигурационную утилиту контроллера, в которую попадают через Ctrl+R при старте сервера.
Но проблема в том, что у меня при старте эта опция вообще недоступна. Только вход в BIOS, вход в Lifecycle, бутменеджер и PXE-бут. Как быть?

Answer (score 0):

Сам спрашивал, сам отвечаю :) Чтобы была возможность зайти в настройки контроллера необходимо с режима загрузки UEFI переключиться на режим BIOS. Тогда появляется опция входа в настройки контроллера.